# Proof: If $S:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|\space f(x)\geq g(x)\}, (s_n)\subseteq S,$ and $\lim s_n=s,$ then $s\in S$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f,g\in C^0$. If $S:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}|\space f(x)\geq g(x)\}, (s_n)\subseteq S,$ and $\lim s_n=s,$ then $s\in S$.

The set $S$ is just the interval(s) such that the the function $f(x)$ is greater than $g(x)$.

I am confused on how the existence of a convergent sequence $(s_n)$ in $S$ implies the existence of the limit of the sequence in the set $S$. What is the role of the set $S$?

Comment: I believe you didn't mention everything you know about $f,g$. Perhaps $f,g$ are continuous? (The statement in the title is wrong otherwise)

Comment: You will need the set $S$ to be closed. For this it is convenient for $f-g$ to be continuous.

Comment: @Yanko see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you know that $s_n$ convergence to some $s\in\mathbb{R}$ but initially **you don't know that $s\in S$**

In order to understand the above consider another example where $A=(0,1)$ and $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$. Then $a_n\rightarrow 1$ but in this example $1\not\in A$ (i.e. it is possible that elements of a given set converge to an element outside the set).

Back to the original question. This is what you need to prove:

You begin with a convergence sequence $s_n\rightarrow s\in\mathbb{R}$, you are given that $s_n\in S$ this means that $f(s_n)\geq g(s_n)$. You need to prove that $s\in S$ that is that $f(s)\geq g(s)$.

In other words you need to show that

> $$f(s_n)\geq g(s_n)\text{ and } s_n\rightarrow s \text{ implies that } f(s)\geq g(s)$$

This follows from the continuity of $f,g$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$\forall n  ,\;f(s_n)\ge g(s_n)$$

thus

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(s_n)\ge ...$$

but $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $s$,

hence

$$f(\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n)\ge ...$$

which means that

$$f(s)\ge ...$$
or
$$s\in ...$$